# AS3 Bytearray to readable format

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have an SWF sending a POST request to a php file. The POST requests contains a byte array from the SWF file, the byte array only consists of unsigned ints. The data sent shows as "eT«cÎìT«au".

I need to know how to convert this AS3 byte array to the original integers, or each value put into an array.

Comment: That's what I need to know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. All I needed was unpack('N*',$data).